# Дерганье слайдера при ресайзе

Tags: html, jquery, slider

Вопрос собственно вот в чем: 
есть сайт http://www.centrsvet.ru/

Там в главном слайдере используется  slick-master, при ресайзе окна картинка дергается. Можно как-то сделать, чтобы этого не было.. Чтобы плавно ресайзилось все?

добавил http://jsfiddle.net/c9fq850y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант - ресайзить с помощью css. 
http://jsfiddle.net/5mxy9b48/
в примере с помощью padding-top расчитывается ширина блока.